# Unable to remove cluster in rancher

Tags: azure-aks, rancher, rancher-rke

I have set up Rancher 2.6.3 on AKS kubernetes cluster (1.21.7), but i was trying to remove AKS Custer from rancher, it is failing with error

```
"{"type":"error","links":{},"code":"PermissionDenied","message","Method DELETE not supported","status":403} ""
```

Answer (score 0):

issue has been fixed, i have to reinstall rancher with 2.6.3 version